# Remote update ec2 instance with docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a release of my project. I build a docker image and deploy it on an ec2 instance. 
Later, when I have a new release, I would like update the docker on ec2 remotely (without accessing the machine, just executing some service).

Is there a way how to do it without ECS and ElasticBeanstalk?

If it's not possible can I somehow re-run the **cfn-init** script?

**My Research**

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-run-command-remote-instance-management-at-scale/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage your instances remotely (i.e. make changes without manually SSHing into the instance and typing commands) by using any of the many system management services out there. AWS offers Simple Systems Manager (SSM) of which the Run Command you linked is part. AWS also offers the OpsWorks service which uses Chef. You also have other products like Ansible and SaltStack, and you can optionally integrate the use of those services with the AWS SSM service.